# React native + IOS app:How to remove the core location library from IOS app?

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native, core-location

1. I haven't used any location related feature in my app.
2. have already removed NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key from
   info.list
3. Build Phases -> Link binary with Libraries : removed the coreLocation.

However, when I extract the app, I could still see the reference of coreLocation library (Note: I have the exe file to run the app to find out the reference)
system/library/frameworks/coreLocation.framwork/coreLocation

I checked react-native modules under node_modules,Though it is not advisable to remove the files from core module,I went ahead and removed all the reference of CoreLocation Library.

[image]

But still I am seeing the system/library/frameworks/coreLocation.framwork/coreLocation reference in extract version of the IOS app

I want to remove the coreLocation library for security reasons.Can anybody help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: And did you delete the RCTGeolocation project from within Xcode's project navigator?

Answer (score 2):

To remove the react native geolocation project from the build, delete the RCTGeolocation.xcodeproj project within Xcode project navigator and clean the build folder (Product -> Alt key and Clean). (To find the build folder, go to File -> Project Settings and click on the small encircled arrow next to the greyed out path in the dialog).

When you have done this, you can see in the resulting product in the build folder that the geolocation library is no longer part of the build. You should also remove the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key from info.list as you mentioned.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I did remove the geolocation project, However I could still see the core location library  reference in app

Comment: No problem. And did you follow the same process as I described in the answer - including cleaning the build folder - because I was able to prove that beforehand the library was in the app and after it was not?

Comment: Yes, I did, However I  could still see the library. Thanks for your help. Anyway, I just added my answer.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by “when I extract the app” in the question? Do you mean you examine the .ipa file? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove the RCTGeolocation.xcodeproj
Remove NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key from info.list 
Build Phases -> Link binary with Libraries : remove the coreLocation library 
Commented all Corelocation library references from react-nativelibrary 
Removed the CoreLocation.h and CoreLocation.m from node_modules/react-native/React/Views
```